# How do I create an HTML anchor in a FogBugz wiki page?

Tags: wiki, fogbugz

The StackOverflow transcripts are enormous, and sometimes I want to link to a little bit within it.

How do I create an HTML anchor in a FogBugz wiki page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing, this feature is now supported -- just edit the wiki page's html directly (via the <> button).

See [this support question](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/create-html-anchors-in-wiki-pages) for details. Use html anchor tags as you would in a typical html doc. (Note that I did have issues w/ FB magically removing the name attribute of the targeted anchors and had to re-add them after an initial save, so YMMV).

Answer (score 4):

According to [this support message](http://our.fogbugz.com/default.asp?fogbugz.4.25208), the feature is not yet currently implemented:

> The FogBugz wiki does not currently support anchors within a document, unfortunately.  It's definitely on the list of features we're considering for the next release, though.

Comment: Just making a note that this answer is now out of date. The feature is available.

Answer (score 1):

There is a script you can use that will [create an automatic TOC for your wiki](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?fogbugz.4.27712.2) page though and this will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Wanted to +1 this, because it would still be useful information. But the link, sadly, is -dead- **broken**. - What happened to [Cool URIs don't change?](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be possible.